How to compile a node-based material system to usable shader code / data buffers / texture resources?
Let's suppose we're rendering a scene using Vulkan with objects with many different materials that are built using nodes.
Within a graphics pipeline, there can be only fixed shader code, so I'll have to upload the entire fragment shading system to the pipeline, and use parameters in a material buffer to switch between materials.
Also, I'll need to upload all textures to the GPU, and traverse the mixing nodes to calculate the final used values.
My question is: is there a more idiomatic and flexible way to switch between materials and textures? Is instancing designed for this purpose?

Your second question has a very simple answer if you do a little research: graphics shaders don't have a stack, so you don't have to worry about overflowing it. Functions in shader code act more like typesafe macros. Any recursive traversal has to be something the compiler can unroll into a linear flow plus simple branches / jumps — if it isn't, it won't compile. I've removed the second question to focus the post on one question at a time.

One option would be to render each model against the material's individual leaf nodes into attachments, then use a composition graphics pipeline (combined with a separate sub render pass) to create the final image. Different materials can be numbered using an integer attachment, and they can be composed using a method simimlar to green-screen keying. Looking around, this seem to have a name: "deferred rendering".
GLSL doesn't support VLA as C99 does, so if it were to be done in shader code, there has to be a lot of custom codes. This is not flexible enough for me.
Please do refute me in the comment if there's any shortcoming of the above approach.

What you've described does not sound like the way that deferred rendering is normally implemented.

It sounds like you're thinking of using one compiled shader to render a wide array of different graphs. This is not usually how it works. Instead, we traverse the graph to write out linear shader code - where each node corresponds to a template of a few lines of code we can stitch together with generated variable names. Then we use this generated code to compile a separate program for each material graph. All the abstractions of node traversal evaporates, and we're left with a list of shader programs we can bind to render our various objects.

Inspecting the code for VulkanSceneGraph and Blender to see how they implement shader graph is beyond the effort I can spare, if someone know about they did it, I'm all ears. @DMGregory you make a point, but as I said in my answer it'll not be flexible enough for me.

Can you describe your use case that demands more flexibility than general-purpose game engines including Unity, Unreal, etc. which all do it this way successfully? I know of only one case where the cost to compile a new shader per material was a limiting factor, and that was a GameCube emulator where they were unable to predict which shaders a scene might need until the moment they needed to render a frame, so background loading wasn't viable. In that case, they were able to use an ubershader approach, but with a much more restricted material system than what you describe.

@DMGregory Sorry, I can't, as I don't have a concrete vulkan-based project right now. What I really want is more like an interpreter than a JIT compiler. What's more, are you sure you can re-combine SPIR-V components to produce per-object material shaders? I always thought you need GLSL source code for that.

You can transpile between the two, so anything you can do with one you can do with the other, with at worst a transpilation pass in between. I think the GPU is not the right place for an interpreter, at least if you're using vertex/fragment shaders. You can get away with more in a compute shader, but you'd have to develop a lot of custom renderer infrastructure for that, and the performance is still likely to suffer substantially over the JIT approach that's standard practice.

@DMGregory "I think the GPU is not the right place for an interpreter" The interpreter runs on CPU, where the app sorts the nodes and place drawing commands in a sub render pass that composes the G-buffers on the GPU. As to performance, only a real benchmark can tell.
